# fatal error minidump

Tags: c#, minidump

I want to write a utility that in the event of a fatal error, a minidump dmp file is created.  I'm using the clrdump api and that seems fairly straightforward.

What I wanted to know is, what should I be reading up on to determine how to trigger an event when there is a fatal error that allows for this minidump to be created.

I will be writing it in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppDomain.UnhandledException is your friend.

Beware that the exception info you can get out of the e.ExceptionObject is almost always more useful than the minidump.  Have you tried minidump debugging yet?  They are invaluable to C/C++ programmers when created in the callback set by SetUnhandledExceptionFilter().  That's not appropriate in a managed program though, the CLR already installs one.  *Not* having to screw around with minidumps anymore and getting clean stack traces is one of .NET's great advantages.

Comment: I have just been asked to look into this by my supervisor.  I think they want to use them when there are problems with internal software, this can be automatically generated and looked at at a later date, rather than relying on user feedback.  I have never done any minidump debugging in my life :)  I am a student on a 12 month industrial placement.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I'll guess that your supervisor is an old C hacker.  Putting an imaginary safety net in place that has a big gaping hole isn't the greatest idea.  But, it's not your problem if you don't want to make it your problem.  Isn't that what internships are all about though?  At least find out what it takes, google "sos.dll".

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I have been looking at sos.dll and i've been able to use it through the Immediate Window.  I have written a small amount of code that generates a dmp file, but now when I open and try to run !dso for example, I get an error that the PDB for mscorwks.dll cannot be loaded so I cannot see any details!

Comment: You have to setup the symbol server to get the pdbs from microsoft.  Tools + Options + Debugging + Symbols.  Start another question about it if you need more help.